# Swift 3 CVaListPointer Type Conflict

Tags: ios, swift3, linphone

I am integrating with a C library - liblinphone.  It has the following typedef and function I need to call from my Swift 3 iOS app.

```
typedef void (*OrtpLogFunc)(const char *domain, 
                            int lev, 
                            const char *fmt, 
                            va_list args);

void linphone_core_set_log_handler(OrtpLogFunc logfunc);
```

It appears that Swift is interpreting `va_list` differently when compiling for the *simulator* than when compiling for a *device*.

Here is the Swift code that uses the C function and

**This compiles only when the target is the *Device*:**

```
class MyClass {
   func setupLogging() {
       linphone_core_set_log_handler(my_callback)
   }
}

func my_callback(_ domain: Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, 
    level: OrtpLogLevel, 
    format: Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, 
    args: CVaListPointer?) {    // NOTE: Optional CVAListPointer
        // do some logging
}
```

**This compiles only when the target is the *Simulator*:**

```
class MyClass {
   func setupLogging() {
       linphone_core_set_log_handler(my_callback)
   }
}

func my_callback(_ domain: Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, 
    level: OrtpLogLevel, 
    format: Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, 
    args: CVaListPointer) {    // NOTE: CVAListPointer is NOT optional
        // do some logging
}
```

When I run on the device, logging works, so it appears that using the optional *CVaListPoint?* is the safest, so how do I get this to compile for the simulator.

The **first** version only compiles and runs on a **device** but issues this compiler error when targeting the **simulator**:

```
Swift Compiler Error
  C function pointer signature 
    '(Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, OrtpLogLevel, 
      Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, CVaListPointer?) -> ()' 
  is not compatible with expected type 'OrtpLogFunc' (aka 
    '@convention(c) 
     (Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, OrtpLogLevel,
      Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, CVaListPointer) -> ()')
```

The **second** version only compiles when targeting the **simulator**, but when targeting a **device**, it issues this error:

```
Swift Compiler Error
  Cannot convert value of type 
    '(Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, OrtpLogLevel, 
      Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, CVaListPointer) -> ()' 
  to expected argument type 'OrtpLogFunc!'
```

Is there some way I can force the simulator to accept this function without changing the C headers?

Or, is there something I can do in Swift to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/) as soon as possible.

And, until this issue will be fixed, this sort of coding would be a workaround:

```
let my_callback: OrtpLogFunc = {domain, level, format, _args in
    let args: CVaListPointer? = _args
    // do some logging
}
```

Comment: This is working.  Thank you!  Now to spend the rest of the afternoon writing up bug reports...